# Why is the while loop not stopping

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and decided to try and make a simple best of 3 rock paper scissors game in which you play against the computer. But when I test the code, even after me or the computer gets 2 wins the while loop doesnt stop.

```py
import random

computerInputList = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
userScore = 0
computerScore = 0

while userScore < 2 or computerScore < 2:
    computerInput = random.choice(computerInputList)
    print("rock, paper or scissors? ")
    userInput = input()
    print()

    if userInput == computerInput:
        print("You played: " + userInput)
        print("Computer played: " + computerInput)
        print()
        print("This round is a tie!")

    elif userInput != computerInput:
        if userInput == "rock":
            if computerInput == "scissors":
                print("You played: " + userInput)
                print("Computer played: " + computerInput)
                print()
                print("You won this round!")
                userScore = userScore + 1
            elif computerInput == "paper":
                print("You played: " + userInput)
                print("Computer played: " + computerInput)
                print()
                print("You lost this round!")
                computerScore = computerScore + 1
        elif userInput == "paper":
            if computerInput == "rock":
                print("You played: " + userInput)
                print("Computer played: " + computerInput)
                print()
                print("You won this round!")
                userScore = userScore + 1
            elif computerInput == "scissors":
                print("You played: " + userInput)
                print("Computer played: " + computerInput)
                print()
                print("You lost this round!")
                computerScore = computerScore + 1
        elif userInput == "scissors":
            if computerInput == "paper":
                print("You played: " + userInput)
                print("Computer played: " + computerInput)
                print()
                print("You won this round!")
                userScore = userScore + 1
            elif computerInput == "rock":
                print("You played: " + userInput)
                print("Computer played: " + computerInput)
                print()
                print("You lost this round!")
                computerScore = computerScore + 1
        else:
            print("Invalid input!")
            print("Accepted inputs: rock, paper, scissors.")
```

I get no error messages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you have a fundamental misunderstanding of the way the `or` operator works in this situation:

```
while userScore < 2 or computerScore < 2:
```

The loop contained in this `while` block will continue to execute if *either* `userScore` **or** `computerScore` is less than 2.

What you're looking for is for the loop to end when one of the two exceeds 2. Change your `or` to `and` to ensure that the loop will only continue when **both** `userScore` and `computerScore` are less than 2:

```
while userScore < 2 and computerScore < 2:
```

Answer (score 0):

you should have a `and` in the while instead of the `or`.

You want to continue when both are below 2.